# Unzip encrypted zip file using it's input stream in JAVA

Tags: java, unzip, password-protection

Need a solution in Java to unzip a huge file(Won't fit in memory) using inputstream. File Object is not available in this case. The file is password protected. Solutions with File object won't help.

I've already tried with 7Zip, But it's not supporting the above case.

Comment: As I've stated already, I don't have file object of the Zip. Say for example, getting this zip from a HTTP request. In such case, the mentioned solution won't work.

Comment: Going into why/how you can't get a `File` would also be helpful, since it would rule out potential answers that rely on the same underlying mechanisms that would let you create such a handle. (If your zip file is being piped to your stdin, but you don't have enough storage to be able to buffer it to either memory or seekable media, you're going to have a very bad day with this request).

Comment: Hacky solution, but may be you can run a `tar -xvf` sort of command from shell using java and pass the path to the file?

Comment: ...if all you have is a FIFO, and not enough storage to stream it to disk, you simply can't read a ZIP file -- zip files use footers, not headers, so you have to be able to go all the way to the end for the index.

Comment: @ClickUpvote, `tar` streams front-to-back. `zip` requires reading the back then jumping back forwards. They're different formats with different requirements.

Comment: My bad, replace `tar` with `unzip` then

Comment: @ClickUpvote, but my point is that you can't pipe to `unzip` *by its nature*, because pipes are front-to-back only, and to parse a zip file, you need to read the end first.

Comment: True, but you can pass the full path to the file. :)

Comment: @ClickUpvote, sure, but if the OP had a seekable handle on the file, they could just get a Java `File` object for it. That they can't get a `File` object almost certainly means it isn't a normal file on their regular filesystem, so they can't pass a path to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541248/unzip-encrypted-zip-in-java?noredirect=1#comment99664483_56541248. I've posted the code and need in another post as this was marked as duplicate.

Comment: When a post is closed as outside site rules, the appropriate action is to [edit] it into compliance (which, for the first such edit, will automatically put it into a queue to be reviewed for potential re-opening), not to re-post. Similarly, when you ask something that's criticized for not having code, you should edit to add the code *in that same question*, not post another instance.

Comment: ...similarly, the right way to disambiguate from a potential duplicate is to include *in your question* a link to that specific potential duplicate and a specific statement of why/how its answers didn't work when you tried them.

Comment: When it was marked as duplicate, it suggested either to edit or repost. I've chosen the second option. Hereafter I'll follow editing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use streams, you should not read more data than requires. have you tried this?

```
   public void unzip(InputStream is, Cipher cypher) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new CipherInputStream(is,cypher));
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (zipEntry != null) {
            File newFile = new File(zipEntry.getName());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
            zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
    }
```

Comment: This looks really useful. Do you have any code on how I can change my password "abc123" into the Cipher?

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems too.
In this repo(https://github.com/r331/memzipenc) you can find a method MemZipDec.unzipFiles(byte[] zipBytes, String password)
I hope it would help.